# Java DataSource SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, datasource, sessionfactory

I'm confused about the difference between `DataSource` and `SessionFactory`.

I think `SessionFactory` is a manager for retrieve Sessions (which are in fact connections to a database I guess).

`DataSource` has the method `getConnection()`

> "Attempts to establish a connection with the data source that this DataSource object represents."

It means a `DataSource` object always works directly with the database?

If I have a pool of connections, `DataSource` will ask to the pool for a connection? Or will it try to get another connection to the database.

Are in fact `DataSource` and `SessionFactory` the same? Both try to give sessions/connections?

Comment: What `SessionFactory` class are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about `SessionFactory`of Hibernate.

Comment: So the `SessionFactory` gives you a Hibernate session and the `DataSource` gives you a JDBC connection. What's the question?

Comment: If I have a pool of connections, `DataSource` will ask to the pool for a connection?

Comment: That's a completely different question, and the answer is that you have it back to front. Normally in that situation the `DataSource` *is* the pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasource maintains the pool of connections, establishes the connection, knows how to connect etc.,

User configures data source either in the server(like websphere/weblogic) or in the spring/hibernate configuration file. Either way you give the handle of this data source to the sessionfactory during the app startup.

SessionFActory is an interface which hides all the details like opening the connection / closing the connections. Through out your development time you dont worry about these small things like loading driver/closing connection/opening etc., so you can concentrate on business logic/other important stuff.